# Windows 8.1/ Server 2012r2 Setting Default Browser vis GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1

I have an RDS 2012r2  server currently has Chrome and IE on it. I am having some issues with chrome and want to get a subset of users using IE instead. I have set two registry keys in GPO as below, this has stopped chrome opening up by default. The problem is, it now asks what browser they want to open with the first time they login. IS there another registry key I can set to avoid this? As they can just pick chrome again.

**Keys I have set**

> Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice[ProgId]
>   = IE.HTTPS Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice[ProgId]
>   = IE.HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8+ no longer allow these settings to be changed via registry to prevent applications from hijacking preferences.  You now have to use specific GPO to set a defaults template, check this article:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrmlcgn/archive/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-a-gpo-e-g-default-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol.aspx#pi86646=4

Basically you need to export settings from a template computer and then apply that XML using GPO.  I was able to verify this works on Windows 8.1 and 10, also works to modify the XML to remove entries you don't want pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Before "playing" with Registry-Hacks try to build an GPO with group policy preferences in the folder settings.

You can set default programs to open file typs here.